When does Congress decide if Trump is eligible to be POTUS?
Earlier this year, SCOTUS rejected the claim by Colorado that since Donald Trump engaged in insurrection on January 6th, 2021, he was ineligible to be on their ballot, citing Section 3 of the 14th Amendment (commonly called the Insurrection Clause or the Ineligibility Clause) and his second impeachment. This ruling states/confirms that only Congress is allowed to say who is allowed to be in the Presidency.
Since Donald Trump gained both the majority popular and Electoral College votes, he is expected to be the next POTUS. However, because of his second impeachment, Congress proved that he was "engaged in insurrection", even though he was acquitted by lacking the 2/3rds majority to convict in the Senate in a 57-42 vote in favor of him being convicted. Section 3 of the 14th Amendment doesn't say that a conviction is necessary to be enforced, but it does say that Congress has to make a special vote to "remove such disability" by 2/3rds majority.
A lengthy Wikipedia article doesn't seem to come to any legal conclusion on whether Trump is eligible or not, however it strongly implies that he isn't eligible. There are objections saying that Section 3 of the 14th Amendment doesn't apply since the presidency isn't explicitly listed as an office of the US or as the position being an officer of the US. However, most of what I read in that article seems to conclude, at least unofficially, that the president is an officer of the US and that the position is an office of the US. Since there is so much contention/confusion/difference of opinions on this topic, I would think that Congress would need to make a final decision on this topic.
After reading a related question that stated Congress convenes on January 6th, 2025 to confirm the Electoral College electors, the linked article says what the process during that Congressional assembly, but it doesn't specifically say when Congress determines eligibility for the president-elect to hold office. Or is that implied by (d)(2)(B) Requirements for objections or questions. with (i) Objections and (ii) Grounds for objections, followed by (d)(2)(C) Consideration of objections and questions?
More simply stated, when does Congress decide if Trump's involvement (proved by his second impeachment) disqualifies him for office? And if they decide that it disqualifies him, when do they decide if they are going to grant him an exception?

It's a little unclear what you are asking, but you might be wondering whether merely having been impeached on grounds including insurrection, without having been convicted, makes someone automatically ineligible. Being impeached but not convicted is like being indicted and not convicted; e.g. in states that have felony voter disenfranchisement, one does not lose one's voting rights after being indicated and acquitted. Even assuming that the Supreme Court and Congress were not conservative-dominated (i.e. they won't disqualify Trump), I'm not sure why you would expect that to be the case.

@Obie2.0, but in that case, the law specifically states "felony". If someone isn't convicted, they aren't a felon. That's pretty cut & dried. Section 3 of the 14th doesn't require conviction, and Trump has been previously proven to have engaged in the insurrection, so it would seem as if Section 3 does apply. I'm asking when Congress makes the decision if it does or doesn't apply. And if it does apply, do they grant him an exception, and when does this granting happen? Is that also during the Jan 6th assembly?

I'm not entirely sure why you think that someone can be an insurrectionist without being convicted, but cannot be a felon unless convicted (insurrection is also a felony, incidentally), but any application here seems more likely wishful thinking than anything else. Congress is not going to "make a decision whether it applies"; at most, someone might file a lawsuit suggesting that impeachment should apply without conviction, which would be very unlikely to be upheld all the way to the Supreme Court, and would certainly take until after his inauguration in any event.

@Obie2.0, again, Section 3 of the 14th Amendment specifically says "engaged in insurrection or rebellion" against the oath they made to support the Constitution of the US. It doesn't say they have to be legally convicted of it. Congress proved that he was directly involved in trying to overthrow the proceedings in Congress, which is in direct violation of the Constitution, which breaks Trumps oath to support the Constitution. Lawsuits are likely to happen either way, and so aren't the concern of my question.

Note that the Supreme Court's ruling was that Congress should enforce the amendment by "appropriate legislation." If Congress had passed, with a simple majority, legislation by which Trump incidentally qualified as an insurrectionist, they might possibly have upheld it against the inevitable challenges, but they seem unlikely to support the idea that impeachment without conviction counts as legislation merely because it also occurs in Congress (to start with, it only requires a majority in the House, without the Senatorial and presidential input that legislation needs).

Under a different legal regime (e.g. case law that does not currently exist in the USA), this might be a good question, but "When will Congress do something that it is quite unlikely to do and that the courts will very likely not require it to do, based on my interpretation of the law which says that they should?" is flawed from the outset, no matter how good your interpretation may be.

In the next to last paragraph, the "objections and questions" refer to the certificates from the states, not to the president's eligibility to hold office.

@Obie2.0, Congress has already proven that Trump was "engaged in insurrection or rebellion", which is his second impeachment. I'm asking when and if they are going to decide to use that to prevent him from taking office. Maybe my recent edit simplifying my question will make it easier for you to understand what I'm asking.

When: never. If: no. Why: because there are a lot of Republicans in Congress, and even many Democrats don't agree with your interpretation.

@RickSmith, maybe I need to ask another question to determine if Electors for someone ineligible to hold office are able to be legally certified?

@Obie2.0, you are assuming my interpretation. I'm asking about when Congress makes the determinization on which interpretation is correct.

The answer, which may disappoint you, is that they will implicitly make the determination by not doing anything. Even if the idea that Trump were automatically disqualified nationwide by impeachment without conviction were absolutely logically unassailable, a Republican majority will not bother even voting to say they disagree with it, and a conservative, largely Trump-appointed court will not try to make them. I'm not sure why you might expect something else.

@Obie2.0, the implication by not going anything will likely gain the lawsuits you talk about. I would think there are Congress members that understand this and want to prevent the lawsuits by making an explicit decision. And I would also think that there would be lawsuits not just about the lack of decision, but possibly lawsuits against specific Congress members, individually, for not making the decision explicit. But talking about lawsuits is getting off topic. If you think they may not make a decision, then you should post an Answer saying so.

If congress was going to declare Trump illegible to hold the office they would have done it long before now.

@JoeW, a citation on he Wiki article shows that Democrats created a bill to state that Trump is ineligible to be POTUS, which was forwarded to the House, but it had a Republican majority, so it didn't go anywhere. Bills are often tried multiple times when Majority leadership is against it. I'd think this could another time Democrats bring up the subject for another try. BTW, that sounds like an Answer, so why not post it as one?

And what exactly has changed? Republicans are still in charge of the house and they will still be in control in the next house as well. I am not posting an answer because I am simply stating the facts that trying to say someone isn't qualified to be president after they are elected to the office is way to late.

To those voting to close : I think the question has merits and gives rise to valid answers (whether you agree with mine or not). The asker's obstination to disregard any other opinion than their own is not a good enough reason to close the question, in my view.

@Gouvernathor, you haven't given a solid reason why Congress can't make this decision. I've given legal opinions from those far more educated than either of us as to why your answer isn't complete or correct. You're the one not listening to the cited Constitutional legal scholars/experts, lawyers, legal precedent, historians, Harvard, SCOTUS, Congress, or the Constitution itself. I've put very little of my own opinion into this question or my comments to your answer. Your opinion is very much in your answer and comments, and it's obvious your political leaning biases your answer.

Short answer : never.
More specifically : as you pointed out, the reasons which can be invoked on Jan. 6 to reject electoral votes are specified in 3 USC 15 (d)(2)(B)(ii), and do not include an ascertainment of whether the presidential candidate qualifies or not.
Though if Congress did it anyway (which won't happen since the Senate went Republican), I'm not sure whether the courts would or could step into it, since it would involve certifying the electoral votes by the courts instead of Congress.
As pointed out here, the time and place to prevent an unqualified presidential candidate is mostly before the election takes place.
In the case of the 14th amendment's disqualification, it has been tried before the election, in Colorado, to remove him from the ballot for that reason. The Supreme Court finally put a stop to that, saying in Trump v. Anderson that this provision of the 14th amendment requires an act of Congress in order to be implemented (relying on 14th§5 : "The Congress shall have power to enforce, by appropriate legislation, the provisions of this article.").
As the words "legislation" clearly states, it must be adopted as a normal (federal, presumably criminal) law, setting forth the rules applying for everyone. The courts would then have the responsibility to apply such rules to particular individual, through the ordinary judicial process. (I could envision federal or state executive branches having a role to play too, depending on what the act says.)
As opposed to the 2/3 vote to "remove such inability", which removes it for certain individuals in particular, not unlike a presidential pardon.
If Congress declared someone in particular to be ineligible for cause of 14th§3, that would be a bill of attainder, forbidden under Art.1 Sec.9 Cl.3 of the Constitution. There are some ways in which Congress or a house may decide something against a particular person, none of which are done through law and all of which are specified in the Constitution : impeachment, expulsion of a member, certifying the election of the president - and in that last case, we already saw how 3 USC 15 sets the 14th amendment out of its reach.
In any case, since such legislation implementing/enforcing 14th§3 doesn't exist, there is no way, according to the Supreme Court, to legally declare Trump to be ineligible due to the 14th amendment, whether at the federal level or in any state.
And even if Congress had adopted such a law between Trump v. Anderson (circa april 2024) and Jan. 20th 2024, or even between Jan. 7 2021 and today, it could very well be considered an Ex post facto law, and be yet again unconstitutional per Art.1 Sec.9 Cl.1 of the Constitution.

In a hypothetical situation where a person would be considered barred, according to the 14th amendment, from holding public office (whether by a SCOTUS change in jurisprudence, or by an act of congress enabling it), supposing that nothing interferes with the process before election day and that they win enough states, there is a question of whether to convene Congress to organize the 2/3 vote to lift the inability. There is also a question of whether to hold it before the Electors cast their votes, or afterwards, but:

in any case, nothing requires Congress to hold such a vote ;
if they do not lift the inability before the Electors cast their vote, there is an open question whether each and any Elector can vote for that person, depending on both state and federal law ;
assuming the previous point does not hold and even one Electoral Vote is sent to Congress to be certified on Jan. 6, I don't see how Congress could legally reject any such EV without a change to 3 USC 15.

There are some steps which could be taken after Jan. 6 (certification) and Jan. 20 (inauguration) against an unqualified president holding office, one of them being to challenge their actions (executive orders...) through the courts. Another way would be impeachment, though there is another hurdle concerning impeachment:

the insurrection would have taken place before the start of the term during which the president would be impeached, and he has already been impeached, tried and found not guilty on that exact basis, so I'm not sure whether that's legal though concerning impeachments Congress itself is usually the final authority on the matter ;
impeachment only applies to officials holding certain offices, and if the would-be president is not qualified to be the president, then they are not the president. So, there is a paradox in that if he is the legitimate president, there's no grounds for impeachment, and if he is not the president, you can't impeach someone that's not holding an impeachable office. But in any case, Congress may find whatever other rationale since it is the only authority on impeachments (cf. Nixon v. United States).

But note that the impeachment way has nothing to do with the 14th amendment, since the amendment does not open another reason for impeaching someone, nor does it need to since Congress can freely decide what constitutes a high crime or misdemeanor as though the 14th didn't even exist.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
